# Create Multimap for every single object in for-Loop

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, multimap

got a little problem, I even know how to fix it theoretically but cant get it going practically.

I got this piece of code:

```
Multimap<String, String> mm = HashMultimap.create();

public MultiMapper(String AttributeName, String AttributeValue)
 {

   mm.put(AttributeName, AttributeValue); }
```

Calling it from here:

```
for(Element attributeFirst : attributeTop.getChildren()) {
    String attributeTopName = attributeTop.getName().toString();
    MultiMapper m = new MultiMapper();
    for(Attribute attributeSecond: attributeFirst.getAttributes()){
       String AttributeName = attributeSecond.getName().toString();
       String AttributeValue = attributeSecond.getValue().toString();
       m.MultiMapper(AttributeName, AttributeValue);
    }
 }
```

The XML-File:

Edit: The only purpose of the main-Method(I changed its name) is to create a new Multimap and fill its fields with values. For example: the first for-loop got 5 Elements, so I want to generate 5 different Multimaps, thats my biggest concern right now, cant get it. The second for-loop contains the values for the map, which are put into the map via put in the main method.

Second question which bothers me: the attributeTopName is the name of the parent-node and I wanted intentionally name the Map like that. But you cannot map Datatype String to Multimap.So how can I put this Attribute into the map as a kind of key, so that when I want to refer to that list, I use the attributeNameTop value to get the Multimap. Like in the Codeexample, instead of mm i want the value of attributeNameTop.

I hope this edit can make it clearer what am I trying to do.

Edit2:
 My Inputfile looks like this, of course with more Lines, wanted to keep it simple. Every line stands for a class in my class diagram, with its Attributes and Values. I want to create an object for every class and save it somewhere for further use in the project. As I loop through the Inputfile, I get AttributeTopName1 as the first class and then a new Object should be created with the same name and the properties I get through the next loop. I tested it, the Input file is right form and the parsing is okay for this task.

```
<Model>
  <Package>
     <AttributeTopName1 Attribute1=AttributeValue1 Attr2=AttributeValue2 />
     <AttributeTopName2 Attribute1=AttributeValue1 Attr2=AttributeValue2 />
  </Package>
</Model>
```

Comment: Please improve your question based on @disrvptor's comments

Comment: Edited the question, I hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the following sentence doesn't make much sense.

> The file contains several objects, which I iterate through in the first loop(attributeTop) and I want to create for every count in the first for-loop an own Multimap.

As the previous comment states the *MultiMapper* should be declared outside of the for loop.  Your code doesn't do anything with the following values

- attributeTopName
- multi

Perhaps you should provide more of the *main* method since it appears to do absolutely nothing that would affect the data in the loop.  Also, are we to understand the *main* method is part of the *MultiMapper* class?

Finally, you really should not overload the method name *main*.  It should be reserved for actual *main* methods.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I edited the question. Would appreciate it a lot if you look over it.

Comment: Andy's answer is correct, you would create a map of String to MultiMap (Map<String, MultiMap>).  However, I also agree with the comment about not rolling your own.  If you didn't want to use DOM or SAX models for parsing the XML then take a look at Jackson's XML binding support.  I believe it will take in a XML file and generate a tree structure for you automatically.

Comment: I used DOM for parsing the XML-File.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `Element` looks something like this:

```
class Element {
    private final String name;
    private final List<Attribute> attributes;
    Element(String name, List<Attribute>) {this.name = name; this.attributes = attributes;}
    String String getName() { return name; }
    String List<Attribute> getAttributes() { return attributes; }
}
```

And `Attribute` looks like

```
class Attribute {
    private final String key;
    private final String value;
    Attribute (String key, String value) {this.key = key; this.value = value;}
    String getKey(){return key;}
    String getValue(){return value;}
}
```

So the data structure your iterating through is a list of lists of pairs:

```
[Element1Name:[[Attr1Key, Attr1Val], [Attr2Key, Attr2Value]],
 Element2Name:[[Attr3Key, Attr3Val],
 ...]
```

Am I right so far?

In your question you say you want to create a separate MultiMap for each Element. If we store each MultiMap in a Map it would look something like:

```
Map<String, Multimap<String, String>> multimaps = new HashMap<String, Multimap<String, String>>();
for(Element element : listOfElements) {
    String elementName = element.getName();
    MultiMap<String, String> mm = new HashMultimap.create();
    for(Attribute attribute: element.getAttributes()){
       String attributeName = attribute.getName();
       String attributeValue = attribute.getValue();
       mm.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
    }
    multimaps.put(elementName, mm);
}
```

Now we can retrieve the required Multimap by calling:

```
Multimap<String, String> mm = multimaps.get("ElementName");
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your answer brought me on the right track, but your code got some minor mistakes in it. One though, I dont understand, whats the listOfElements? You didnt declared it anywhere. I know you are iterating through all elements, but how, without declaring it anywhere?

Comment: In your code you're retrieving some array or Iterable by calling attributeTop.getChildren(). I'm not sure where that comes from or the type of the object or the return type of the function so I just renamed it listOfElements to make to make it clear that I was guessing it was a List<Element>.

Comment: Actually I got an XML File, where I get my Information. So the data I get is a String. Practically I got 3 String: AttributeTopName = Element.Name; AttributeName, AttributeValue. What you are suggesting is to put all the attributeTopName Elements in a list?

Comment: No, I wouldn't suggest doing that. I was just answering your question as it was written. I didn't realise you were parsing xml. You probably want to use a pre-existing xml parser rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Perhaps we could be of more help if you include the following data in your question: 1. What data you are provided with 2. What you want to do with that data. Ingesting data into a data structure is a means to an end, but I don't know what the end is, so it's difficult to know if you're on the right path.

Comment: Hey Andy, I edited my question, look at Edit2. Your suggestion with the Maps in a Map sounds good, somehow I dont get it working. Hopefully you understand what I want to do.